# PHP cannot display updated values

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, session

I'm trying to display the updated value in `showName` div but my website only displays the updated value **only after logged out and logged in again**.

1. update username by pressing `saveName` button.
2. successfully updates username in PHPMyAdmin `users` table.
3. `showName` div still displays the old username. Even if I refresh the page.

**index.php**

```
<div id="showName">
<?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['userId'])){
        echo $_SESSION['username']; }
?>
</div>
<div id="message"></div>
<div> <input id="editName" name="editName" /> </div>

<button id="saveName" type="submit" >Save</button>
```

**edit.php**

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

include_once('database.php');

$validUser= $_SESSION["username"];

if(isset($_POST['editName']))
{   
    $username = $_POST["editName"];

    if ($username =="") {
        echo "Enter your full name.";
        return false;
    }else {
        $sql = "UPDATE users SET username='$username' WHERE username='$validUser'";

        if(mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
            echo "Successfully Updated.";
        } else{
            echo "Something went wrong"; }
    }
    return false;
}
    ob_end_flush(); 
?>
```

**script.php**

```
$("#saveName").click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    $.post("edit.php",
    $("#editName").serializeArray(),
         function(info){ $("#message").html(info);
    });

});
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Hint: If you're pulling data from the `$_SESSION` then you must update that as well if you're changing it in the database.

Comment: @tadman I actually have a function that uses `trim()`, `stripslashes()` and `htmlspecialchars()` for `$_POST`. I'm wondering how to update `$_SESSION` when I update database at the same time?

Comment: That method is completely inadequate, it doesn't properly protect against injections. Use prepared statements with placeholder values. Additionally to update `$_SESSION` usually you just assign to it. How did you set that value in the first place? That way.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the new username to session once it updated in database.
`$_SESSION["username"] = $your_new_username`

```
<? php
ob_start();
session_start();

include_once('database.php');

$validUser = $_SESSION["username"];

if (isset($_POST['editName'])) {
  $username = $_POST["editName"];

  if ($username == "") {
    echo "Enter your full name.";
    return false;
  } else {
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET username='$username' WHERE username='$validUser'";

    if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
      echo "Successfully Updated.";
      $_SESSION["username"] = $username // Updating the new username to session
    } else {
      echo "Something went wrong";
    }
  }
  return false;
}
ob_end_flush(); ?>
```